# front end Type script

Tags: typescript

I want to convert typescript code into js code but I got this error :

```
tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I tried to write this commit and I expected that it would convert the code from TS to JS and create another file with the same code but with the Js extension.

Comment: That implies that the TypeScript compiler isn't installed, or the console couldn't find it in the PATH, please share more about what you did to install the compiler to the console, as well as you operating system.